# How to disable self-hosted agent in AzureDevOps pool via command-line

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

We have multiple self-hosted build agents in out AzureDevOps and I want to automate their maintenance.
(things like Windows updates or VSbuild tools)

I want to disable the agent in the pool so it doesn't receive build tasks while updates are running.

Does anyone know how to do this via command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to do this via command line?

Instead of CMD, you can use Powershell.exe(`Cmd.exe is not recommended for calling azure devops rest api`) in your local machine to disable any self-hosted agent via this rest api:

```
Patch https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/{PoolID}/agents/{AgentID}?api-version=5.0
```

Request Body:

```
{
    "id":{AgentID},"enabled":false
}
```

**Details:**

1. Go Organization settings=>Agent Pools=>Choose the pool that host your self-hosted agent=>Check the `Agents` tab and click one of your agent to see details. Then you can find `PoolID` and `AgentID`.

   [image]
2. Now let's create a [PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) to authenticate into Azure DevOps. Only Agent Pools's Read&Manage access is enough.

   [image]
3. Assuming my organizationName is `TestOrganization`, then my final powershell script would be:

(You can run it in Windows Powershell ISE)

```
$token = "wjqtxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxtgiga"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/TestOrganization/_apis/distributedtask/pools/10/agents/9?api-version=5.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$JSON = @'
{
    "id":9,"enabled":false
}
'@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Patch -ContentType application/json -Body $JSON
write-host $response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
```

With the $token(Your PAT), PoolID and AgentID, you can easily control which agent to be `enabled/disabled` via the `"enabled":xxx(true or false here)`. Note that you need to replace the `agentID` in both URL and Request body.

Comment: Yea that works. That's basically what I was looking for but couldn't find in the API documentation.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did it in Python

```py
import requests

def disable_enable(pool_id: int, agent_id: int, headers:json, enable:str):
  """Disable or enable an ADO agent

  Args:
      pool_id (int) : The ADO pool ID to analyze
      agent_id (int): The ADO agent ID to disable
      headers       : The ADO headers
      enable (bool) : True to enable, False to disable
  """
  payload={"id":agent_id,"enabled":enable}
  r = requests.request("PATCH",("https://dev.azure.com/swissre/_apis/distributedtask/pools/" + str(pool_id) + "/agents/" + str(agent_id) + "?api-version=7.0", headers, payload)
  print("Agent {} enable: {}.".format(agent_id, enable))
  rJson = r.json()
  print(rJson)
```